# kubernetes artitachture for building apps that sync clients in real-time?

Tags: kubernetes

supposed that I want to build an app like google doc or a multi-player online game with k8s. clients (like a web browser or an app installed on a user's phone) who hit the service endpoint are most likely to be load-balanced to separate pods (where the web server is deployed; the web server might use something like WebSocket to sync with clients). what is the best practice to sync to pods together without introducing a single point of failure?

Comment: What do you mean of "sync clients"? Are you storing the client data inside web server?

Comment: client data would eventually be written to a database by the web server. how other pods are notified (passively, actively monitoring the db, or some other ways) when the state changes is what I'm trying to figure out

Comment: You can query the database in interval if load is not heavy. Or you can also have a pub/sub way(message queue, service discovery or socket).

Comment: querying from the database at a set interval doesn't apply to my use case because the latency is guaranteed to be at least that interval. I've considered using Firebase Realtime Database but I don't want to be locked into GCP. A message queue sounds like a good idea.